# db2 : last schema update for Procs/tables

Tags: database, db2, database-schema

How do I find when the last schema/ddl change was done for a given proc/table in DB2 , I intend to write a script which can compare the schema update date to the last release date(which will be input to my script) and on that basis update procs/tables from (say)dev to stage .. stage will be the master list for modifications and dev will be master for new additions .

So something like eg. Modification changes

If lastschemaupdateindev  > releasedate
Update to stage

Does db2 store the schema updates per proc/table in some system table… skimmed through the syscat tables didn’t find anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB2 9.7 for Linux/UNIX/Windows (LUW), IBM added the column ALTER_TIME to syscat.tables.  Earlier versions of DB2 LUW did not track this information in the system catalog.

For stored procedures in DB2 9.7, you should be able to refer to ALTER_TIME or CREATE_TIME in syscat.procedures.  In prior releases, CREATE_TIME should be sufficient (as you only had the option to drop and recreate a procedure to make a change).